# How to store a String in a String Label

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

I am writing a program in which user inputs a string. This string is stored in a register $v0 by default, but I want to copy the data inside $v0 to String label, so that if I use $v0 for other purpose in the program, the user input doesn't get corrupt. I get figure out how to do it. I will be very glad if someone could tell me how to do it.

Regards

Comment: Which `syscall` are you using? Can you post whatever code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

In *Spim*, the service to read a string from the user is service *8*, which takes as argument:

- `$a0`: a pointer to the buffer where the string will be written
- `$a1`: the size of the buffer

Upon return of the *syscall*, the buffer will be ovewritten with the input text (up to a maximum of `$a1` bytes), `$v0` is unaffected

Example usage:

```
.data
buffer: .space 128

.text
  la $a0, buffer
  li $a1, 128 # maximum number of bytes to be read
  li $v0, 8
  syscall
```

Comment: What is li $a1,128 is doing? Where did you copied the user input from $v0 to buffer?

Comment: @user1698102: The `syscall` to read a string from keyboard receives in `$a0` a pointer to the buffer where the string will be stored and in `$a1` the size of that buffer (that is, the maximum number of bytes to be read from console). You don't have to use `$v0` to read a string from keyboard. Note that `$v0` is just another register (32 bits wide) so it really cannot hold the actual string read.